# Expo-auth-session is returning code instead of token (standard authorization flow)

Tags: authentication, expo, authorization, openid-connect, expo-auth-session

I'm setting up an expo application with a local docker keycloak server. I followed the [expo step-by-step](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#keycloak), and after calling the `promptAsync` method, I've got a `type: success` response. However, I'm not receiving any token. This is my request result.

** prompAsync result**

```json
{
   "authentication":null,
   "error":null,
   "errorCode":null,
   "params":{
      "code":"6d054370-129b-43cf-8a50-4d9b66d71ee7.5e0ae876-fee5-49f7-ac89-9dbf03c1c620.b3055e80-ee68-4a53-b118-788efca721fe",
      "session_state":"5e0ae876-fee5-49f7-ac89-9dbf03c1c620",
      "state":"R6H8w3tArj"
   },
   "type":"success",
   "url":"myapp://home?state=R6H8w3tArj&session_state=5e0ae876-fee5-49f7-ac89-9dbf03c1c620&code=6d054370-129b-43cf-8a50-4d9b66d71ee7.5e0ae876-fee5-49f7-ac89-9dbf03c1c620.b3055e80-ee68-4a53-b118-788efca721fe"
}
```

I know that in the standard authorization flow, we receive a `verified code` which we exchange for a toke with the server. How can I request this token?

This is my implementation:

```js
const Login = () => {
  WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession()
  const discovery = useAutoDiscovery(`${SERVER_URL}realms/${REALM}`)

  const [request, result, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      redirectUri: makeRedirectUri({
        scheme: APP_SCHEME,
        path: 'home',
      }),
      scopes: ['openid', 'profile'],
    },
    discovery
  )

  const handleOnPress = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await promptAsync()
      console.log('login response: ', response)
      console.log('result: ', result)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('login error: ', e)
    }
  }

  console.log({ result })
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        title="Login!"
        onPress={() => {
          handleOnPress()
        }}
        disabled={!request}
      />
      {/* {result && <Text>{JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)}</Text>} */}
    </View>
  )
}
```